# Creating string from table with .each, how to add a newline after each row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am grabbing the data out of selected cells of a table with this javascript:

```
var cellIndexMapping = { 0: true, 1: true, 3:true, 4:true, 5:true};
var data = [];

$j("#myTable tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    $j(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex])
            data.push($j(this).text()  );
    });
});

var fullCSV = data.join(", ");
console.log (fullCSV);
```

This gives me all of my table elements in a comma separated array.  So for example if my table is

```
<th>| zero | one | two | three | four | five | </th>
---------------------------------------------
<tr>|  A   |  B  |  C  |  D    |  E   |  F   | </tr>
---------------------------------------------
<tr>|  G   |  H  |  I  |  J    |  K   |  L   | </tr>
```

I get back :

```
A,B,D,E,F,G,H,J,K,L
```

What I need to have is a newline `"\n"` between each row.  So my desired result would look like :

```
A,B,D,E,F,\n G,H,J,K,L \n
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cellIndexMapping = { 0: true, 1: true, 3:true, 4:true, 5:true},
    data = [],
    finalData = [];

$j("#myTable tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    data.push([]);

    $j(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex])
            data[rowIndex].push( $j(this).text() );
    });
});

$j.each(data, function(i, e) {
    finalData.push( e.join(',') );
});

finalData.join("\n");
```

---

Alternatively, you could just append `\n` in every loop:

```
var cellIndexMapping = { 0: true, 1: true, 3:true, 4:true, 5:true},
    finalData = '';

$j("#myTable tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    var data = [];
    $j(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex])
            data.push( $j(this).text() );
    });

    finalData += data.join(', ') + "\n";
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLsW5/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add it at the end of the outer loop:

```
var res = "";
$j("#myTable tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    var data = [];
    $j(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex])
            data.push($j(this).text()  );
    });
    res += data.join(", ") + "\n";
});
```

Now `res` holds the final value.

Comment: Thanks, this works but now I have a comma at the beginning of every line.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still can not get it to return correctly with this.  Joesph's solution worked well for me so I will just roll with that.

Comment: @Zac - That's cool. For future internauts, here's a fiddle showing that this approach works: http://jsfiddle.net/Nqq2r/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want the trailing comma in the first line? Don't you want something like:

```
A,B,D,E,F\nG,H,J,K,L\n
```

Here is a way using [`.map()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var cellIndexMapping = { 0: true, 1: true, 3:true, 4:true, 5:true};    

var fullCSV = $j("#myTable tr").map(function() {

    return $j(this).find("td").map(function(cellIndex) {
        return cellIndexMapping[cellIndex] ? $j(this).text() : null;
    }).get().join(', ');

}).get().join('\n');
```

Comment: Yes that was a typo.  I was just getting [object HTMLTableCellElement] returned though.  I am using Joseph's solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Forgot to change the inner `each` to `map`. It works now: http://jsfiddle.net/KPWr6/2/