# Line breaks in in JavaScript printing

Tags: javascript

Some PHP script to get values
returns

```
[[9,16,0],852.2],<br>[[9,17,0],850.85],<br>[[9,18,0],849],<br>[[9,19,0],848.7],<br>
```

But I need,

```
[[9,16,0],852.2],
[[9,17,0],850.85],
[[9,18,0],849],
[[9,19,0],848.7],
```

If something has to be changed, suppose "a" is the solution code, then a is added to each line

```
[[9,16,0],852.2],a
[[9,17,0],850.85],a
[[9,18,0],849],a
[[9,19,0],848.7],a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try "\n" : new line

[Javascript Strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Or try to modify the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735553/creating-string-from-table-with-each-how-to-add-a-newline-after-each-row)

Hope this helps

Comment: When an answer has solved your problem, remember to Accept it by clicking the gray check-mark (tick mark) and turning it green. That will let everyone else know you've gotten the answer you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `<br>` with `\n`

A new line character (\n) will take the content to another line. If you want to add any character before new line add it while doing the replacement.